# Emacs26 on Windows 7, Why is Setting Mark shortcut toggling language instead?

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacs26

I just installed Emacs26 on my Windows 7 64-bit computer and whenever I try setting a mark `ctrl + <space>`, it toggles the Windows language settings instead. `M-x set-mark-command` works as expected though.

Comment: Probably a shortcut that Windows is intercepting before Emacs gets it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something happening between when you press `C-<SPC>` and when that signal is sent to Emacs.  The path from key press to action on the screen is surprisingly complex.

To troubleshoot it, first make sure that any obvious stuff is turned off.  Disable any application like AutoHotKey.

From there, things are trickier to handle.  However, it seems that `C-<SPC>` is a common problem with Chinese keyboards.  Might you be using one?

If so, [this super user post is relevant](https://superuser.com/questions/363873/how-to-disable-ctrl-space-selecting-chinese-keyboard-on-windows-7).  The relevant content  is from user [Kache](https://superuser.com/users/161249/kache) and is given below (for posterity).  If it helps you, make sure you jump over to the original post to give the author credit.  I'm just a middle man.

> ## Procedure
>
> 1. Go to `Start` > Type in `regedit` and start it
> 2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method/Hot Keys`
> 3. Select the key named:  * `00000070` for the `Chinese (Traditional) IME - Ime/NonIme Toggle` hotkey  * `00000010` for the `Chinese
>      (Simplified) IME - Ime/NonIme Toggle` hotkey
> 4. In the right sub-window, there are three subkeys.  * Key Modifiers designate <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>/etc and is
>      set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (`02c00000`).  * Virtual Key designates the
>      finishing key and is set to <kbd>Space</kbd> (`20000000`).
> 5. Change the first byte in `Key Modifiers` from `02` to `00`
> 6. Change the first byte in `Virtual Key` from `20` to `FF`
> 7. Log off and log back on. I don't think it's necessary to restart.
> 8. Do not change the `Hot keys for input languages` in Control Panel, unless you want to do this all over again.
>
> **Notes: Symptoms**
>
> Each registry key (thing that looks like a folder) is for each
>   specific hotkey setting that you would normally find in `Control Panel
>
> > Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages > Change keyboards... > Advanced Key Settings > Hot keys for input languages`. The recurring bug is the hotkey being automatically reset to
> >     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> even if changed via the GUI.
>
> This is for Windows 7 64-bit, though from my research, it looks like
>   it may work for XP and Vista as well.
>
> Sources:
>
> [Traditional Chinese Pocket IME Hot Key Registry Settings](https://superuser.com/questions/363873/how-to-disable-ctrl-space-selecting-chinese-keyboard-on-windows-7)
>
> [Simplified Chinese MSPY 3.0 IME Hot Key Registry Settings](https://superuser.com/users/161249/kache)
>
> [1](https://superuser.com/questions/363873/how-to-disable-ctrl-space-selecting-chinese-keyboard-on-windows-7): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904366.aspx
>     [2](https://superuser.com/users/161249/kache): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms904626.aspx